# How to handle javascript alert/pop up window: Python+Selenium IE webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver

The webpage I need to go to has a javascript popup message with an OK button that appears before the page can finish loading.
There's ways to get rid of the message by either clicking the button, pressing enter, pressing the x to close, or pressing ALT+F4.  But all attempts to either click or press keys fails and just remains on the page with the popup.

I must be missing something.
Everything is current and installed, even the registry additions for the IE server executable.

Thanks

Comment: What specific commands have you tried?

Comment: send_keys(Keys.ENTER) or RETURN, both didn't work. I included the from selenium....keys import Keys and all that. I've tried switch_to.alert, .accept(). Nothing. However, when I put it line by line in the Python shell, it works (the alert accept, it made the pop up go away.) but if I run it as the whole .py file, nothing.

Comment: Please put what you've attempted into a nice, readable code block in your question.  In the meantime I think you may want to consider some sleeps/waits.

Answer (score 0):

If this Java popup is generated by IE you could be able to handle it using Alert(driver).accept()
I have run into this issue a couple of times where the popup is not part of IE at all and this does not work. there are a couple different methods you can try to get around this:

1. try switching your browser to phantomJS (this is a headless browser that works with selenium and runs in the background so you will not be able to see what selenium does anymore but it often will eliminate popups and is good if you don't actually need to click the popup)
2. try using the [mouse](https://pypi.org/project/mouse/) or [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) packages to hit that button.